# Laravel Voyager admin menu links are not correct

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I installed the new Laravel voyager and set it up as the documentation said but I'm facing a problem in the links of the admin menu 
for example, "http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/admin" is showing as "http://localhost:8080/admin"
in my .env file, the URL is: APP_URL=http://localhost:8080/mywebsite
what am I missing

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the problem is the URL was cached and even `cache:clear` and `config:cache` commands did not solve it. what I had to do is to delete the laravel app and start over

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug (I am the author of the Github issue).

https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3993

https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/4008